# Copying field expression field calculator

Tags: qgis, expression, field-calculator

I would like to know, how I can see the code behind a attribute field in the attribute table of a shapefile layer in QGIS 3.16.
I have created a new data column with a specific code used in the field calculator. However, now I want to copy that code and use it for creating a new field in another layer.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see which expression was used to create/change a field via the attribute table. But you may expand the `latest` dropdown in the field calculator where the last 10 to 20 expressions you used are listed.

Comment: And when/if you create a virtual field the formula is available in field properties (layer properties / field tab)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Somehow laborious that created expressions for fields cannot be seen for each field individually, but your comments definitely helped a lot.

Comment: @Kevin_S2021 if you're running the same workflow with the same expressions over and over, you may create a model.